# See what icons are included in icon font file

Tags: icons

A project that I'm working on is making use of icon fonts. Is there some way of seeing what icons are included in the file? I can see what the icons are labeled in the generated css file (i.e. .icon-mail-alt:before { content: '\e808'; } ), but I would like to see the what the "images: look like. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mac you can open it in fontbook and see all of the characters/symbols available.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a PC. Don't judge me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On PC you can use charmap.exe, though it hasn't changed significantly in decades and is no longer really great.  A quick search turned up [BabelMap](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) as an alternative which looks much more usable.

Answer (score 0):

Icons are usually mapped to characters between `0xe000` - `0xefff`
You can print these characters on the page that includes the icon font. Run in browser console:

```
var fontFamily = 'ICON-FONT-FAMILY';
var range = [0xe000, 0xefff];
var items = [];
for (var i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
  items.push('<b class="icon">' + String.fromCodePoint(i) + '</b>');
}
document.body.innerHTML += items.join(' ') + '<style>.icon{font-family: "' + fontFamily + '"; font-size:32px !important; margin: 5px;}</style>';
```